# How to use classes in Referenced Libraries in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have imported the algs4.jar file as a referenced library as seen above. All seems to be fine but I can't seem to use or access any of the classes in the library.

Is there an import statement I'm missing?

Image reference:

[image]

Note how I'm trying to use `BinarySearch` from the referenced library but it is not offering me an option to use or import it.

Comment: You can do `ctrl+shift+o` and eclipse will add the necessary imports. From your error it looks like you are missing the jar containing `BinarySearch` class in the build path.

Comment: I have the same problem... with the same algs4.jar :))

Answer (score 7):

I am taking an [Algorithms](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI) class via Coursera that utilizes the algs4.jar reference library.

**The Problem:**

The issue you are having is that the reference library is located in the default package and the source in which you are accessing the reference library is not.

**The Solution**

All classes in your project need to be in the default package, otherwise the reference libraries (which are located in the default package) will not be recognized.  Your project classes need to be in the src directory and you should not declare a package at the beginning of your .java files. Additionally you also need to make sure you've [added the reference libraries to your build path](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29).

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure, I did not try this. Some interpretations though.

Is this a standard library or someone created it by himself and gave you?

The problem is class `BinarySearch` is in `default` package. You will not be able to import it. If this library is created by you, or by any of your friend, you need to ask your friend to move all classes from default package to a good namespace and then re-create the jar.

If class is accessible, `ctr + shift + o` should import the class.

Comment: That's what I started thinking. So I unzipped the jar added it into a package. Now I can use an import statement ("com.package.*") and I can even create a new reference to the class ("BinarySearch bs = new BinarySearch()". However, on runtime I get a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Additionally, I also get this error message: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: @jeffstern - You cannot just unzip and move `.class` files. You require the source. For each `.java` file change the package declaration to something suitable and then export as jar. The existing `.class` files still have old package declaration, i.e. `default`. Moving them to desired package will not change package declaration and hence your import won't work.

Comment: Mm yes, that makes sense. I'll go back to the original creator of the library and see if they can recreate it with a standard package structure. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the classes in the jar files are all contained in the default package.

If your classes are then contained in a package then they will not be directly accessible.

I submit this answer because I am taking the algorithms course to which these jar files belong and this was the specific cause of my program not working.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Classes in the `default` package are not accessible by classes in other packages. This has nothing to do with being in a references library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import the classes, you need to download the packaged version of the library. See the Q&A section at the bottom of this webpage.
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

> Q. If I use a named package to structure my code, the compiler can no longer access the libraries in stdlib.jar. Why not?
>
> A. The libraries in stdlib.jar are in the "default" package. In Java, you can't access classes in the default package from a named package. If you need to use our libraries with a named package, you can use the packaged version stdlib-package.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, BinarySearch can not be created (private Constructor). Use the static Method `BinarySearch.rank(int key, int[] array)`

Secondly you can access BinarySearch only from **default package**

Thirdly what about `Arrays.binarySearch(array, key)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete module_info.java file and the referenced libraries are accessible instantly