# How to use libraries for Algorithms part I Coursera course in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I've started Coursera [Algorythms course](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI). Practice assignments must be done on Java and they suggest using DrJava as IDE, but it's really unconvenient. So I'd like to use Eclipse, but the problem is that I couldn't use 2 libraries([algs4.jar](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/algs4.jar) and [stdlib.jar](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/stdlib.jar)), which are provided for this course. After doing steps from [this guide](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~elancast/labta/eclipse.pdf) I was able to include them in my project:

[image]

but when I try to use their classes in my project, Eclipse doesn't allow to do it, and I couldn't import them by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>:

[image]

And even when I am trying directly import class like `import stdlib.StdRandom;` it still doesn't work.

What can I do to make it work properly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why don't you use these two JARs—— stdlib-package.jar and algs4-package.jar.

And below the code page(http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/)

Q. If I use a named package to structure my code, the compiler can no longer access the libraries in stdlib.jar or algs4.jar. Why not?

A. The libraries in stdlib.jar and algs4.jar are in the "default" package. In Java, you can't access classes in the default package from a named package. If you need to use our libraries with a named package, you can use these package versions: stdlib-package.jar and algs4-package.jar.

Warning: if you are taking Princeton COS 226 or Coursera, Algorithms, Part I or II, you must use the default package verison of our libraries to facilitate grading.

Showing my test success:
[image: Showing my test success]

Answer (score 12):

You can't access the APIs because the authors have defined them in the default package and Java doesn't recognize these. The authors mention on their website (http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/) that if you are using these in named packages, configure your build path to include the jar from http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/algs4.jar.

HTH!

Comment: UPDATE: As of August 17, 2015 it is now only one package: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/algs4-package.jar . Classes from stdlib-package.jar are already contained in algs4-package.jar. Sourse: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/

Comment: UPDATE: The package path has changed since previous comment, and now it's https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/algs4.jar

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect the situation as of May 2020.

Comment: UPDATE As of  11 oct 2021 algs4.jar and stdlib.jar here https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

Answer (score 6):

Follow the below steps

Right click on your project > Properties. It will open the following window

[image]

Select "Java Build Path" from the left side.  Now select "Libraries" tab from the right side

[image]

Click on "Add External Jars"

[image]

Add the Jar files.

Now you are done

Comment: I've done everything as u described and got libraries imported, but again cannot use anything from them: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0wZAG.png
Could you try download this libs: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/stdlib/stdlib.jar, http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/algs4.jar and import them yourself?

Answer (score 5):

All you should have to do in order to include the JARs is right click on the top of your project/object tree in the project explorer panel on the left, do "Build Path/Configure Build Path", click "Libraries" tab, and "add external jars", add them there.

They should happily become available both while editing your source code and while building it in Eclipse after that.

Also note that, assuming you have the class name right when you type, you should be able to hover over the class name in your code and the intelli-sense/auto-complete feature will suggest where you should import it from.  You can add the import to the correct library that way with ease.

Comment: Library has been added, but I still couldn't use classes. 
Could you try download this libs: introcs.cs.princeton.edu/stdlib/stdlib.jar, algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/algs4.jar and import them yourself?

Comment: I added the jar and could use BinaryIn and Picture classes fine which are both defined in it.  I didn't even need an import statement actually which was curious; It looks like the classes aren't defined in a package when you open them up through eclipse by browsing the referenced assemblies (after adding them to the build path in the way this answer states above).  So, not sure what your problem is.  Make a new Eclipse project and try again from scratch just doing this, sometimes Eclipse gets confused and intellisense stops suggesting classes in my experience; remaking the project fixes it.

Comment: I've recreated projects and workspaces many times, but that doesn't helped at all. Using link provided by Khalid Amiri I recognized that problem can be that this libs are using (default) package. So now I am trying to find how could I use classes from default package...

Answer (score 2):

One option is that there is a [maven repo on github](https://github.com/slok/algs4-mvn-repo) provided by [slok](https://github.com/slok). The bad part of this is the jars added were those using the default package, so you can't use a package structure.

**UPDATE**: I have added the package versions of the jar to the repo and <s>created a pull request</s> it has now been accepted.

Note that I have changed the identifiers to match the original package structure from Princeton.

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>edu.princeton.cs.introcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>algs4-package</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>edu.princeton.cs.introcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>stdlib-package</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>org.coursera.algs4</id>
    <name>Algs4 coursera course custom repository</name>
    <url>https://raw.github.com/slok/algs4-mvn-repo/master</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 2):

From their website: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/

> Eclipse (manual). Download stdlib.jar and algs4.jar to a folder and add each jar >file to the classpath variable to the build path of a project via Project -> >Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libaries -> Add External JARs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are anyone still looking for the solution :-

OS X / Linux

`% javac -cp .:stdlib.jar MyProgram.java
% java  -cp .:stdlib.jar MyProgram`

Windows

`% javac -cp .;stdlib.jar MyProgram.java
% java  -cp .;stdlib.jar MyProgram`

For refrence :- https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

Answer (score 2):

Incase of Gradle, add the maven repository entry in repositories section of build.gradle as follows:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/algs4/maven/'
    }
}
```

Add the dependency as follows:

```
compile group: 'edu.princeton.cs', name: 'algs4', version: '1.0.4'
```

In case of Maven, add the entry in repositories tag in build.xml, as follows:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>org.coursera.algs4</id>
    <name>Algs4 lib</name>
    <url>https://dl.bintray.com/algs4/maven/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Add the dependency as follows:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>edu.princeton.cs</groupId>
    <artifactId>algs4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because there is no package structure in the libraries, so you can't import classes from it. This might help you, [How to use classes in Referenced Libraries in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924736/how-to-use-classes-in-referenced-libraries-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Gradle**. In this case the **build.gradle** file should have a dependency and can look like

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'edu.princeton.cs:algs4:1.0.3'
}
```

After this you can import anything from it in your class. For example:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
```