# Why there is an Exclamation point when I add algs4.jar?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse. I have tried the ways in  [How to use libraries for Algorithms part I Coursera course in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008099/how-to-use-libraries-for-algorithms-part-i-coursera-course-in-eclipse) . But it always appeared an Exclamation point as in the picture. How can I solve it?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhfgT.jpg)

Comment: Look in the "Problems" view and it's very likely you'll see a helpful message there...

Comment: you are missing some dependent jars in your project try to look into project properies->build path configuratio

Comment: What is your problem and your question? Don't put links into your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks! I find some messages in the "Problems", one of them is"the project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved".

Comment: @JekinKalariya Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @buhtz I am sorry for I am not familiar with this. I have uploaded a picture but it display as a link.

Comment: Your picture does not show the useful parts, like the error messages in the "Problems" view. The one you mentioned is the least important, you need to find out what build path errors are there. You could start by right-clicking the project, Build Path, Configure Build Path, Libraries tab and if some entries there have a red cross those are libraries that are missing.

Comment: @LibrarerTseng My comment wasn't about any picutre. It was about the link. Don't put link in a question where no one knows what is behind it.

Comment: @SantiBailors Thanks, the problem is solved.

Comment: @buhtz Thanks for your suggestion. I will avoid this next time ：).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be for any of the following:

- Inconsistency of the project's configuration file like .classpath/.project which cause problem in Java Build Path / JRE System Library.
- Out of Sync code with your Software Configuration Management System like SVN etc, due to the network, permission or file merge problem.
- Most Common is Project did not open correctly when you have started Eclipse.

Solution 1. -

Right click on your project -> Close Project. it will Close your project and all opened file(s) of the project
Right click on your project -> Open Project. it will Open your project and rebuild your project, Hope fully it will fix red exclamation mark

Solution 2. -

Right click on your Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path. Can you see missing in front of your library file(s) as per following screen-shot
Click on Add Jar to select your Jar file if it is the placed in WEB-INF/lib of your project or Add External Jar if jar file placed somewhere on your computer
Select the old missing file(s) and click on Remove

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elIj5.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I have solved the problem!