# Netbeans. Can't import package. Package doesn't exist

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, jar

I'm an iOS developer and now I have to work a little with `Java`. I'm using `Netbeans 8.0` on OSX 10.11.5 . I've added `algs4.jar` file to my project the following way: I selected `Libraries`, then selected `Add JAR file / folder` so now it is in my project. But still I can't import a package from that jar. It says:

```
error: package edu.princeton.cs does not exist
```

I tried adding the jar file different ways, tried locating it in different folders but nothing helps. Any ideas, guys? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the same issue that in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008099/how-to-use-libraries-for-algorithms-part-i-coursera-course-in-eclipse. Namely, include those 2 JARS instead: `alg4s-package.jar` and `stdlib-package.jar`